# Bash : Adding extra single quotes to strings with spaces

Tags: bash, variable-expansion

When I try to passing arguments as variables to any commands in bash I can see extra quotes added by bash if the variable value has spaces.

I am creating a file "some file.txt" and adding it to a variable $file.
I am using $file and storing it in another variable $arg with quotes on $file.
The the command I am hoping for after variable expansion by bash was

```
find . -name "some text.txt"
```

but I got error and actual file that got executed is,

```
find . -name '"some' 'file.txt"
```

Why is this happening. How bash variable expanson works in this case?

```
$ touch "some file.txt"
$ file="some file.txt"
$ arg=" -name \"$file\""

$ find . $arg
find: paths must precede expression: file.txt"
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

$ set -x
$ find . $arg
+ find . -name '"some' 'file.txt"'
find: paths must precede expression: file.txt"
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

Why this is happening?

Comment: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: This kind of annoying stuff is why, after about 1 hour of shell scripting, I always slam my head into a wall

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quotes in the value of a parameter are treated as literal characters after the parameter is expanded. Your attempt is the same as

```
find . -name \"some file.txt\"
```

not

```
find . -name "some file.txt"
```

To handle arguments containing whitespace, you need to use an array.

```
file="some file.txt"
# Create an array with two elements; the second element contains whitespace
args=( -name "$file" )
# Expand the array to two separate words; the second word contains whitespace.
find . "${args[@]}"
```