# Bash array variable expansion inside expect command

Tags: bash, expect, variable-expansion

An extension to this question :
[Bash : Adding extra single quotes to strings with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33871500/bash-adding-extra-single-quotes-to-strings-with-spaces)

After storing the arguments of command as a bash array

```
touch "some file.txt"
file="some file.txt"
# Create an array with two elements; the second element contains whitespace
args=( -name "$file" )
# Expand the array to two separate words; the second word contains whitespace.
find . "${args[@]}"
```

Then storing whole command in an array

```
finder=( find . "${args[@]}" )
```

In bash I am able to run the command as below:

```
"${finder[@]}"
./some file.txt
```

But when I tried using expect, I am getting error

```
expect -c "spawn \"${finder[@]}\""
missing "
   while executing
"spawn ""
couldn't read file ".": illegal operation on a directory
```

Why is bash variable expansion not happening here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`expect -c COMMAND` requires COMMAND to be a single argument. It doesn't accept multi-word arguments, which is what `"${finder[@]}"` expands to.

If you want to handle whitespace perfectly without mangling it'll be tricky. `printf %q` might be of use.

Answer (score 0):

`${finder[@]}` in double quotes expands into separate words:

```
$ printf "%s\n" expect -c "spawn \"${finder[@]}\""
expect
-c
spawn "a
b
c"
```

So, `expect` is not getting the entire command as a single argument. You could use `*`:

```
$ printf "%s\n" expect -c "spawn \"${finder[*]}\""
expect
-c
spawn "a b c"
```

`${finder[*]}` expands the array elements into a single word separated by the first character of `IFS`, which is space by default. However, there is no distinction between spaces added by `*` and the whitespace in the original elements, so, you cannot reliably use this.

Comment: Try this with the user's original arguments; you'll get `spawn "find . -name some file.txt"`.

Comment: @chepner added note about that.

Comment: Providing an answer for a question about `bash` arrays that only works if the elements of the arrays don't contain whitespace is not useful. The entire reason for arrays to exist is to handle elements that contain whitespace.

Comment: The actual error actually seems to be the very first quoted `"`, so I don't think you've addressed the problem at all.